# Is there an api I can fetch to return a curl value?

Tags: node.js, curl, get

I recently noticed that some sites block node-libcurl but not curl. Is there an api that I can fetch to return the actual curl response? I used [reqbin](https://reqbin.com/curl) and tried to mimic the requests they sent, but to no avail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

many websites (for example wikipedia.org) blocks user-agents lacking a `User-Agent` header, curl has a default user-agent, it looks like `curl/7.73.0` , but libcurl does not hence when you make a request with libcurl, it doesn't have an useragent and will be blocked many places, the solution is [CURLOPT_USERAGENT](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERAGENT.html)